# How to use this defined type in C?

Tags: c, typedef, type-definition

How can I use this defined type ?

```
typedef void (*(workers[2]))(char *, char *, int);
```

What I could understand, that I'll have `workers`, which is an `array` of `two` `pointers`, each one points to a `void`, which accepts the mentioned arguments.

Is that correct ?

**Trial #1**

```
void worker1(char * x, char * y, int z) {

}

void worker2(char * x, char * y, int z) {

}
```

and then inside some another void, I did:

```
workers w;
w[0] = worker1;
w[1] = worker2;
```

Compiling, I get:
`` error: cannot convert `void (**)(char*, char*, int)' to `void (* (*)[2])(char*, char*, int)' ``

Comment: Looks more like an array of function pointers to me.

Comment: [cdecl](https://cdecl.org/?q=void+%28*%28workers%5B2%5D%29%29%28char+*%2C+char+*%2C+int%29%3B)

Comment: Two function pointers, each function returns nothing and takes 3 parameters.

Comment: Close. Better worded as *points to a function that returns `void` and accepts accepts the mentioned arguments.*

Comment: What happens when you tried it?

Comment: It would be better to separate the function pointer declaration from the array declaration to make things easier to read and understand: `typedef void (*worker)(char *, char *, int); worker workers[2];`

Comment: Thanks for commenting everybody, I did update the question with my trial, can you check please ?

Comment: @thb has provided a complete example. If it works, you can "accept" the answer. If it doesn't you can comment the answer. If you change your question, everybody get's confused, including yourself. That's especially true if you add code that is just wrong like a `workers W;` (with uppercase W) and `w[0] = worker1;` with lowercase w;

Comment: Isn't there a handy web util that lets you enter this sort of thing and spits out the result of parsing?

Comment: @TimRandall cdecl. See Eugene's comment (currently) second from the top.

Comment: @harper, I did fix the typo, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`workers` is an alias for the type "2-element array of pointers to functions taking two `char *` and an `int` as arguments and returning `void`".

Here's an example of what this beast might look like in practice.

```
void f0( char *foo, char *bar, int bletch )
{
  // do something interesting with foo, bar, and bletch
}

void f1( char *foo, char *bar, int bletch )
{
  // do something else interesting with foo, bar, and bletch
}

int main( void )
{
  workers w = { f0, f1 }; // equivalent to void (*w[2])(char *, char *, int ) = { f0, f1 };

  // call f0 through w:
  w[0]( "blah", "blah", 1 );

  // call f1 through w:
  w[1]( "ugh", "blah", 2 );
  ...
}
```

The `workers` typedef basically creates a shorter name for a complicated, hard-to-read type.  In practice, it would probably be better to create a typedef for just the function type, then create an array of that:

```
typedef (*worker)(char *, char *, int );
worker w[2] = { f0, f1 };
```

The problem with a declaration like

```
workers w = { f0, f1 };
```

is that it's not immediately obvious that `w` has an array type, so the initialization looks confusing.  It also relies on the person using this type to *know* that it's an array type of a certain size.  We call that a "leaky abstraction", and they lead to confusion and maintenance headaches.

You still have to know that each `w[i]` is a function type that takes a certain number and type of arguments, so ideally that should be hidden behind an interface as well (i.e., you pass `w[i]` to a function that knows how to call it, rather than calling it yourself).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose:

```
typedef void (*(workers[2]))(char *, char *, int);
workers my_workers;
```

The `workers` is a type (really, an alias for a type). The `my_workers` is an object of the `workers` type.

The `my_workers` is an array of two pointers, each pointing to a *function.* Each such function accepts the mentioned arguments and returns `void`.

**TRIAL**

As your request, I have tried your code as follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void (*(workers[2]))(char *, char *, int);

void worker1(char * x, char * y, int z) {
    printf("1: [%s] [%s] [%d]\n", x, y, z);
}

void worker2(char * x, char * y, int z) {
    printf("2: [%s] [%s] [%d]\n", x, y, z);
}

int main() {
    char sa[] = "here";
    char sb[] = "there";
    char sc[] = "everywhere";
    char sd[] = "nowhere";
    workers w;
    w[0] = worker1;
    w[1] = worker2;
    (w[0])(sa, sb, 50);
    (w[1])(sc, sd, 70);
    return 0;
}
```

Try that. For me, it compiles and runs with no warnings, no errors.

Comment: I did try and updated the question, can you check please ?

Comment: Thanks, it is clear for me and could implement and use it smoothly, thanks.